# Loading different piece of configuration every request

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.0

I have an app where I'd like to load different config sections based on a header coming from the request
Here is part of my startup.cs
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllers();

```
        IConfiguration cfg = null;
        services.AddScoped<IConfiguration>(x =>
        {
            cfg = Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings:" + x.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>()?.HttpContext?.Request?.Headers["xxx"]);
            return (cfg);
        });

        services.AddSingleton<DB.Calendar.Repo>(x => new DB.Calendar.Repo(cfg));
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();
    }
```

Problem is nothing inside the lambda of AddScoped gets called at all (even if I just put some console.outs) so cfg stays null. What am I doing wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The delegate passed to `services.AddScoped()` is only executed when a new scope is created (i.e. at the start of a HTTP request for ASP.NET apps). Which explains why `cfg` is `null` when `AddSingleton()` is called.

Something like this should work:

```cs
services.AddScoped<DB.Calendar.Repo>(x => {
    var cfg = Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings:" + x.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>()?.HttpContext?.Request?.Headers["xxx"]);
    return new DB.Calendar.Repo(cfg);
});
```

Once you've got it working, it'd be wise to move the logic that reads the correct configuration section to its own service, to make it more testable (and also make it look clean).

Comment: That's it. So simple. I straight up almost had a stroke figuring this out. ASP Core's way of doing things is not all that clear coming from OG .net platform.

Comment: @americanslon just a matter of time until you get the hang of it. It's pretty consistent throughout.